# 3 relays with a latching relay

Tags: relay, dc, 12v

I have looked for a product that has 3 relays, 1 NO and 2NC with one NC being latched.  Does anyone know of the existence?  How about how to build one? 12V DC as well.

Comment: I think answering questions on where to buy stuff is beyond the scope of this site but I suspect you won't find anything off-the-shelf so maybe there is an alternative way of approaching things but given you haven't stated anything about the relay contact ratings how could anyone advise (or even recommend a place to buy such a product). Providing info = helping your self to a better answer rather than me blabbing on in a comment.

Comment: Relays with double-throw contacts are much more common than single throw (except for reed relays).  As Andy says, you are unlikely to find a pre-assembled package with this (or any) combination of relays.  You will have to search the suppliers to find relays to meet your needs, and package them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about the contacts associated with a relay.  Any Normally Open contact on a relay can be wired to make the relay latch.

Comment: This is not answering the OP's question - it does not help him discover what he's looking for. Plus, how could you possibly answer with that proposal - the OP may in fact want a relay that needs to have the coil supply reversed before unlatching - these exist but your proposal wouldn't cover that functionality because the contact would revert to NO when power is lossed. I'm not downvoting because the question is poorly framed but you should consider that others may not think the same and possibly down-vote your answer.